# Drupal questions - customizing form_altered modules

Tags: drupal, forms, hook, element, alter

This week I have figured out how to modify form elements in the location module
using form_alter and the custom `element hook_elements()` : [need some tips on Drupal $form value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637052/need-some-tips-on-drupal-form-value)

I was able to to hide elements using unset eg: `unset($element['locpick']['user_latitude']);`

Also added css with drupal_add_css to hide unwanted groups, and change margins, borders & padding

However, I have a few questions:

- how can I add additional text header between fields?
- how can I change input field length?
- is it possible to move fields around or put them in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also added css with drupal_add_css to hide unwanted groups

I highly advise against this. Use the Form API proper to control forms.

Comment: I guess this would not be very transparent and could confuse administrator who may not aware of these operations in modules.

Comment: Its the proper way to do it. If a form can't be changed in the permissions for a role then form_alter and other form hooks get the job done. You can't just hide fields with CSS- that immediately makes the forms inflexible, especially if future modules are relying on them.

Answer (score 0):

learn this: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6

1: set weight of two fields, for example, to 10 and 12. Add new "item" field with weight 11.
2: see "size" in top link.

Comment: This approach seems very tedious. Can I somehow capture form values and create a new template with these values?